# How to write a nested object using protobuf syntax?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I would like to convert this nested object to it's equivalent in protobuf syntax:

```
{
  where: {
    id: string | { equals: string }
  }
}
```

So the `id` field could either be a string or an object with a single key called `equals`.

I tried a little bit and did some research, but I just couldn't figure out how.

```proto
message UserRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

message UserQuery {
  UserRequest where = 1;
}
```

And of course, I want to avoid using `google.protobuf.Any`.

Comment: Check out [oneof](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof)

Comment: @DazWilkin I have tried it, but I couldn't get the same structure I want. If you could, please add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```proto
message Foo {
  oneof where {
    string id = 1;
    Bar bar_message = 2;
  }
}

message Bar {
  string equals = 1;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what i'm looking for. It's important the same field name is used `id`.

Comment: @OmarDulaimi how doesn't it fit your use case? This looks quite accurate to me

Comment: @ClémentJean He's using id and bar_message, what I want that both fields using the same name `id`, so that I get the same original structure, with the same names.

Comment: Please read the [oneof](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof) documentation and you'll see that you cannot do what you want. The `oneof` needs a name and each of the sum types must be named. You could name the `oneof` `id` but then you'd need another name for the string field.

Comment: @DazWilkin Exactly, that is why I asked you to post an answer, because I couldn't get it to work with oneOf or with anything that my little search showed me. And hence why i'm asking here, for the help of experienced people that might know if this is really doable in some little known ways.